# How to display dynamically fetched image on client end in react?

Tags: reactjs, image, axios

I'm working of Gallery feature of my website where I wanna show all images to client. I have successfully fetched images from server to client end in the form of blob. Images also display but on second attempt. I need to visit that gallery page for first time for fetching images then I need to visit any page and re-visit that gallery page for displaying those images.

Here is my code. Kindly let me know where I'm making mistake.

Code of main Gallery Component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        eventDetail: [],
        images: [],
        imagesInBlob: [],
        url: ''
    }
    this.getAllEventsData = this.getAllEventsData.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllEventsData();
}

getAllEventsData() {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/GetAllEventsData',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {},
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            eventDetail: response.data
        });
        this.getAllImages();
    }.bind(this))


}

getAllImages() {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/GetAllEventImages',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {},
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            images: response.data
        });
        this.getImageBlobs();
    }.bind(this))
}

getImageBlobs() {

    console.log("Image Objects:", this.state.images);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.images.length; i++) {
        this.fetchEventImage(this.state.images[i].image_path);
    }
    this.setState({
        imagesInBlob: imageArr
    });
    console.log("Images in Blob:", this.state.imagesInBlob);
}

fetchEventImage(imagePath) {
    var path = {
        ImagePath: imagePath
    }

    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/ImageFetch/FetchEventImages',
        responseType: 'blob',// important
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: path
    }).then(function (response) {

        var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));

        imageArr[img_arr_cnt++] = url;
        console.log("URL: ", url);

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Status:", error.response.status);
        console.log("Data:", error.response.data);
    });
}

handleImageDisplay() {
    var imgTag = "<img src=" + this.state.imagesInBlob[0] + '" />';
    return imgTag;
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <section id="single-project" className="section">
                <div className="container row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <div className="row justify-content-center">
                            <div className="col-lg-6 project-info">
                                <h3>Meeting on 17th May 2019</h3>
                                <DisplayComp propName={this.state.imagesInBlob[0]} />
                                <img src={this.state.imagesInBlob[0]} />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section >
        </>
    );
}
```

DisplayComp component code

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}


render(){
    return (
        <img src={this.props.propName} alt="image"/>
    );  
}
```

Please let me know where I'm making mistake and how can I display it on client end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your code. You've some problems with asynchronous calls and also not all functions are bound to `this`. I would suggest to convert your code to async/await to make it more readable and use named functions, because they are automatically bound to `this`.

```
getAllEventsData = async () => {
    const response = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/GetAllEventsData',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {},
    })
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({
            eventDetail: response.data
        });
    this.getAllImages()
}
```

In `getAllImages` it's neccessary to wait for `setState` to be finished, because `getImageBlobs` is using the state value and `setState` is asynchronous.

```
getAllImages = async () => {
    const response = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/GetAllEventImages',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {},
    })
    console.log(response);
    await this.setState({
            images: response.data
        });
    this.getImageBlobs();
}
```

In `getImageBlobs` there is a loop over a asynchronous function. So you need to wait till all calls are finished. `Promise.all` will help here. Also `imageArr` is some magically created global variable which is bad practise. Better return the value from `fetchEventImage` and collect it in a local array. I replaced the for-loop with a map, which basically does the same, but looks cooler and cleaner and returns an array with all the Blob-URLs as `Promise`. Also destructuring `images` from `this.state` helps cleaning up the code.

```
getImageBlobs = async () => {
    const { images } = this.state
    console.log("Image Objects:", images);
    const imageArr = await Promise.all(
                        images.map(image => this.fetchEventImage(image.image_path))
    this.setState({
        imagesInBlob: imageArr
    });
    console.log("Images in Blob:", this.state.imagesInBlob);
}
```

Also in `fetchEventImage` async/await looks cleaner and with try/catch you can do the same for error handling. As stated, this function will now return the created Blob-URL.

```
fetchEventImage = async (imagePath) => {
    var path = {
        ImagePath: imagePath
    }
    try {
      const response = await axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/ImageFetch/FetchEventImages',
          responseType: 'blob',// important
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          data: path
      })
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      console.log("URL: ", url);
      return url
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Status:", error.response.status);
        console.log("Data:", error.response.data);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the refactored code. Maybe there are some minor mistakes, but I think in general it should work.

Comment: First of all I wanna tell you, your code worked perfectly. But left me with lots of questions. One of the main questions is  why you preferred to use of **Async/Await** and **Promises**? I'm not familiar with the use of Async/Await so would like to know more about it and why you thought it'll perfectly fit to my use case?

Comment: Async/Await will keep the code more in sequence and you can see right at the beginning, if these method uses promises. With the old `then`,`catch` style the code is more nested, although it behaves like a sequence. And for me more complicated to read. But it's totally fine if you use the normal promises.

Comment: You said, `it keep the code  in sequence` but I didn't get in what sense? As per my understanding asynchronous function not run in sequential way. May you're refering to different context. Please clear my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `fetchEventImage`. You are not setting state, no `this.setState`. That is why your component does not rerenders. Try Promise.all.

```
getImageBlobs() {

    console.log("Image Objects:", this.state.images);

   const promises
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.images.length; i++) {
         promises.push(this.fetchEventImage(this.state.images[i].image_path));
    }
    Promises.all(promises).then(imagesInBlob => {
    this.setState({
        imagesInBlob
    });
    })
}

fetchEventImage(imagePath) {
    var path = {
        ImagePath: imagePath
    }

    return axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/ImageFetch/FetchEventImages',
        responseType: 'blob',// importaqnt
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: path
    }).then(function (response) {

        var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));

        return url
        console.log("URL: ", url);

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Status:", error.response.status);
        console.log("Data:", error.response.data);
    });
}
```

Sorry for any style issues, I answered on my phone

Comment: It's throwing an error at `promises.push(this.fetchEventImage(this.state.images[i].image_path))` this line.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @Talgat and thank you for taking interest in my question. Answer by Auskennfuchs is worked for me.